# A problem in console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Can you explain to me about the problem at the red cross in the image and how to fix it? I can't understand what is happening.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4F4u.png

Comment: Don't use images if you can use text. Please provide the source code, it seems like a syntax error, but it is hard to say from the image only.

Comment: I added this script to the console:

Comment: I can't paste the script to comment line because it is too long